# SELECT INTO equivalent in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have been easily using 
`SELECT * INTO newtable IN 'another_database'
FROM original_table_in_separate_database;`

to backup/copy data from one table to another table easily in MSSQL.

Now i am moving to MYSQL and cannot accomplish this task as this feature is not available in MYSQL.

Though  `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` can somehow accomplish the task in same database, but not with two different database.

Please help me if there is any idea :)

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Just use `database.tablename` for the `create table` clause.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) construct like

```
INSERT INTO db1.dbo.newtable 
SELECT * FROM db2.dbo.original_table_in_separate_database;
```

Point to note: For `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` to work both the target table and inserting table must exist. Otherwise, use `CREATE TABLE AS ... SELECT` like

```
CREATE TABLE newtable
AS
SELECT * FROM db2.dbo.original_table_in_separate_database;
```

Comment: i am talking about different database.. but INSERT INTO..SELECT is for same database.. and table should exist already.

Comment: NO, they can be for different databases as well. See the example in answer. In answer, db1 and db2 stands for two different databases.

Comment: newtable doesnot exist ERROR :(

Comment: Here is my error :( 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxS6Oq-jD3PhQnNydkF6Sk95eTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Newtable must exist in prior. Check edited answer. Refer MySQL documentation for more information.